# My site has no css on android default browser

Tags: android, css, mobile-safari

I found out that when I browse my site in Android's default browser, the site is loaded without the design defined in the css file.
(The same site looks well designed on IE7, IE8, FireFox, Chrome and Safari)

I'm not really sure what the problem can be...
I'll appreciate any idea

Thanks

Comment: We can't know without seeing any code. Does the CSS file get loaded?

Comment: What version of Android? Is there a any public website with which you have the same problems? Can you publish on the Internet a small page and css the demonstrate the problem?

Comment: This happens on all android versions, I'll try to create a public example to demonstrate the problem

Comment: How can I make sure the CSS file is loaded? Is there a way to see that in the emulator?

Comment: Have you checked the server, do you get a request at all? Without public code it's hard to help you.

Comment: Can you post your <link> tag(s)?

Comment: I'm working on a public example for this problem, but in the mean time... any idea why the browser doesn't request the css file?

Answer (score 1):

> I'll appreciate any idea

Check your HTML and CSS at the [W3 validator](http://validator.w3.org)

Comment: Thanks, this did find some errors on my page. I'll work on resolving them and see if this fixes the problem

Comment: OK, so I fixed all the problems on the HTML and CSS, and still it looks the same. I'm still trying to understand how can I see that the CSS file was loaded when using the emulator...

Answer (score 1):

A bit late in the day, but thought I'd leave a comment on this for other users that come across this question.

It's worth checking if the css is compiled/compressed. I have found that loading an uncompressed css file for specific android browsers has fixed the issue (although I still have various other issues that I'm working my way through :( ...at least the css file is loading now though!)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to check your web server logs. If UA (user agent) is being logged, you'll be able to see if the Android browser requested for your CSS file.

Comment: I've checked the logs, and the browser doesn't requests the css (or any included js file for that matter). What might be the reason for that? (in general of course)

Comment: Perhaps there is server-side processing going on, which causes the css file not to be served to the Android browser. Is there any way you "view source" from the emulator and check if the same HTML is being loaded?